# Queue of methods in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

My goal is to have a Queue of method calls contained in a class that extends Thread whose run method pops a method call off of the queue once every 15 seconds. This could be done in a shady way using Strings, ints, or chars in a mammoth switch case, but I was wondering if anyone else has a far more elegant solution to this issue.

Something that would look like this?

```
public class Potato extends Thread{
    Queue<Methods> methodsQueue = new LinkedList<Methods>();

    public Potato(){}
    run(){
        methodsQueue.poll();//This would execute a method
    }

    //Methods of this class...
}
```

Comment: I think you'll want to look into the [Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

Comment: Take a look into executor API

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: As @danielbathke suggested, the executor API would be a great place to start. Specifically, the `ScheduledExecutorService` can handle queueing as well as delays between method calls.  See this link:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Comment: As @DennisSoemers suggested, the Reflection API is available. I know a lot of developers cringe when they hear the word Reflection, but if you need ultimate flexibility in which methods get run or you just can't force every object in your queue to implement a pre-defined interface, Reflection would work quite well. Just be very careful if you go that route :)

Comment: @danielbathke I would use the executor service however the method I execute may be different every execution. So the method being executed every 15 seconds may be different every 15 seconds, and the queue may be empty at times and no command may be executed.

Comment: @CodeBlind I'd like to avoid cumbersome and notoriously difficult APIs as the java code will execute on an Android system that will be prone to issues to begin with.

Comment: The simple solution, a java.util.Timer that executes every 15 seconds that grabs from a queue of some single function interface type that you fill easily with generic actions by writing lambdas.

Comment: This one liner (which is available in the Android API) gives you the same functionality you're trying to implement: `ScheduledExecutorService s = Executors.newScheduledThreadpool(numThreads);` If you need to run arbitrary methods using reflection, then submitting them to this service is as easy as wrapping each one in custom Runnable argument and calling `s.schedule(Runnable,long,TimeUnit)`.  I can't think of a more elegant, less cumbersome solution to your problem (at least when using Java). And it comes with the benefit of having been tested and used as part of the core Java API since 2004.

Comment: @CodeBlind I think the ScheduledExecutorService was exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use an interface to wrap the  methods you want to call:

```
public interface MethodWrapper {
  void execute();
}

public class Potato extends Thread{
  Queue<MethodWrapper> methodsQueue = new LinkedList<>();
  public Potato(){}
  run(){
   methodsQueue.poll().execute();
  }

//Methods of this class...
}
```

Comment: `Runnable` would work, that's true. the important thing is to handle a queue of some class type and not methods

Comment: Hint: you might want to mention that this could be called *Command* pattern. One can do a lot of interesting things around this approach. And god beware, without using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

This one liner (which is available in the Android API) gives you the same functionality you're trying to implement:

`ScheduledExecutorService s = Executors.newScheduledThreadpool(numThreads);`

If you need to run arbitrary methods using reflection, then submitting them to this service is as easy as wrapping each one in custom Runnable argument and calling `s.schedule(Runnable,long,TimeUnit);`

I can't think of a more elegant, less cumbersome solution to your problem (at least when using Java). And it comes with the benefit of having been tested and used as part of the core Java API since 2004. – @CodeBlind